# How to get product option value from quote_item_options table in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I want to get product option from `quote_item_options`.

I want product option from item which is added to cart.

I just call event `checkout_cart_product_add_after` and in that observer i want product option

so which model is use to get that data in magento 2?

Comment: In which context?

Comment: @MauroNigrele sorry i didnt get you

Comment: I'm asking you, in which context you need to get that model ie inside a controller or cron or wathever

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT 2** Based on the edited question

The event `checkout_cart_product_add_after` send 2 parameters.

- quote_item
- product

So I guess that you can get the options either from the QuoteItem or Product as well.

```
public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
{
    $quoteItem = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
    $options = $quoteItem->getOptions();
    // Do something with options
}
```

**EDIT**

If you are trying to get the options from a loaded Quote / QuoteItem you can call:

```
$quoteItem->getOptions()
```

But if you need to load options outside a quote or an specific quote_item you can use `Magento\Quote\ResourceModel\Item\Option\Collection` to grab such data.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER** (Completely Wrong) but may be useful for someone.

Looking in the database seems like `sales_order_item_options` doesn't exists anymore but now there is a `product_options` text field in the `sales_order_item` so I guess that the product options should be saved (serialized) there.

Try to load `Magento\Sales\Order\Item` and `getProductOptions();`

Or if you have already loaded the Order Model try to get them by calling `$order->getAllItems()`

Hope my idea helps

Comment: I dont want from sales order i want it from cart

Comment: Sorry i'm a kind of stupid in that case is like in M1 Magento\Quote\Item\Option (I need to sleep)

Comment: @Newbie check out my edited answer